# Tiptap - OnNodeActive / onMarkActive event?

Tags: prose-mirror, tiptap

I want to be notified that a node or a mark is active (after a click or a keyboard move).

With VUEJS, the isActive is reactive in the template (passed in slot), but can we do it in javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able check prosemirror transaction's [selectionSet](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/version/0.20.0.html#state.Transaction.selectionSet) property to define if selection was changed by this transaction ( when applying a transaction in yur plugin). And then get active node from trsnsaction's [selection](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#state.Transaction.selection) property.